# MySQL Time and Date query problems

Tags: mysql, date, time

I want to make a query which returns me some values between two dates and two times...

The DATE and TIME values are in different columns, DATE is called FECHA and TIME is called HORAIN

I have 4 possible values with just a DATE query:

Value 1 has Date 2012-05-07 time 02:45:00
Value 2 has Date 2012-05-07 time 12:00:00
Value 3 has Date 2012-05-08 time 04:35:00
Value 4 has Date 2012-05-08 time 07:30:00

What I want to get, is the results from 07:00:00 to 23:59:59 from the first day, and values from 00:00:00 to 06:59:59 from the second day (so an interval from 07 AM to 06:59 AM)

This is my query, which is returning NO VALUES... It must return me VALUE 2 and VALUE 3, because it matches my desired requirements

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE
(DATE(fecha)>='2012-05-07' AND TIME(horain)>='07:00:00')
AND
(DATE(fecha)<='2012-05-08' AND TIME(horain)<='06:59:59');
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If so, can you include them in your question?

Comment: You'd better paste the Schema of the table. For example, the data type of "fecha" is TEXT or Datatime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch result using `Concat()`. It concatenating two fields value.so You can concatenate `fecha` with `horain` field value and then search for results like given below .

```
SELECT *   FROM `mytable` WHERE (Concat(`fecha`, ' ', `horain`, '') <= '2012-05-08 06:59:59') AND (Concat(`fecha`, ' ', `horain`, '') >= '2012-05-07 07:00:00')
```

`Concat()` function take 4 parameter.

1. `Value1`
2. `String from which concatenate value1 to value2`
3. `Value2`
4. `String want to concatenate in last`

Hopefully it will be helpful for you

thanks.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you :D I set fire to my brain trying to get it very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it one step at a time - eliminate as much restrictions and see if you get records - when you get them, add one condition at a time:

start with:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

continue with:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE
 DATE(fecha)>='2012-05-07'
```

and so on, until you find the condition that cuts out all your records and see why that is happening

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FECHA >= 2012-05-07 AND horain >= 07:00:00)
AND FECHA <= 2012-05-08 AND horain <= 06:59:59 );`

Comment: I got the same problem, I tried that too before the query I posted :(

Comment: Try to adjust your database so date and time are saved in one record. To do this, you can use the DateTime field type. Then do `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MyDate >= 2012-05-07 13:23:04 AND MyDate <= 2012-05-08 06:59:59 );`

Answer (score 0):

The time and date are checked separately

If we restructure your where clause and leave out the date part you get:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE TIME(horain)>='07:00:00' AND
TIME(horain)<='06:59:59'
```

This will never give you a result since both can never be true.
what you can do, is combine the date and time fields

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE
concat(fecha,' ',horain) as date BETWEEN '2012-05-07 07:00:00' AND '2012-05-08 06:59:59';
```